# BigQuery best approach for ETL (external tables and views vs Dataflow)

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, etl, google-cloud-dataflow

CSV files get uploaded to some FTP server (for which I don't have SSH access) in a daily basis and I need to generate weekly data that merges those files with transformations. That data would go into a history table in BQ and a CSV file in GCS.

My approach goes as follows:

- Create a Linux VM and set a cron job that syncs the files from the
  FTP server with a GCS bucket (I'm using GCSFS)
- Use an external table in BQ for each category of CSV files
- Create views with complex queries that transform the data
- Use another cron job to create a table with the historic data and also the CSV file on a weekly basis.

My idea is to remove as much middle processes as I can and to make the implementation as easy as possible, including dataflow for ETL, but I have some questions first:
What's the problem with my approach in terms of efficiency and money?
Is there anything DataFlow can provide that my approach can't?
any ideas about other approaches?

BTW, I ran into one problem that might be fixable by parsing the csv files myself rather than using external tables, which is invalid characters, like the null char, so I can get rid of them, while as an external table there is a parsing error.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your ETL will be simplified by Google DataFlow Pipeline batch execution job. Upload your files to the GCS bucket. For transforming use pipeline transformation to strip null values and invalid character (or whatever your need is). On those transformed dataset use your complex queries like grouping it by key, aggregating it (sum or combine) and also if you need side inputs data-flow provides ability to merge other data-sets into the current the data-set too. Finally the transformed output can written to BQ or you can write your own custom implementation for writing those results.

So the data-flow gives you very high flexibility to your solution, you can branch the pipeline and work differently on each branch with same data-set. And regarding the cost, if you run your batch job with three workers, which is the default that should not be very costly, but again if you just want to concentrate on your business logic and not worry about the rest, google data-flow is pretty interesting and its very powerful if used wisely.

Data-flow helps you to keep everything on a single plate and manage them effectively. Go through its pricing and determine if it could be the best fit for you (your problem is completely solvable with google data-flow), Your approach is not bad but needs extra maintenance with those pieces. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

here are a few thoughts.

If you are working with a very low volume of data then your approach may work just fine. If you are working with more data and need several VMs, dataflow can automatically scale up and down the number of workers your pipeline uses to help it run more efficiently and save costs.

Also, is your linux VM always running? Or does it only spin up when you run your cron job? A batch Dataflow job only runs when it needed, which also helps to save on costs.

In Dataflow you could use TextIO to read each line of the file in, and add your custom parsing logic.

You mention that you have a cron job which puts the files into GCS. Dataflow can read from GCS, so it would probably be simplest to keep that process around and have your dataflow job read from GCS. Otherwise you would need to write a custom source to read from your FTP server.

Here are some useful links:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#autoscaling

Comment: In this context, what's a not a very low volume of data?

Comment: I like federated resources because it's just too simple :) , things like autodetect, etc., it just seemed right :P.. However that null char is a problem that make me believe I have no other choice. Now with Data Flow I'm thinking on creating a pipeline per file pattern (I would just provide the schema and the pattern as arguments). Then I guess I can use the views to remove the duplicates